# Programmatically enable GZIP Tomcat 7 (embedded)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, embedded-tomcat-7

I am using Tomcat7 (embedded)

Something like this...

```
String APP_DIR = "ROOT";
Tomcat current = new Tomcat();
File file = new File(APP_DIR);
if (file.isDirectory() && file.canRead()) {
    ctx = current.addWebapp(null, "", file.getAbsolutePath());
    ctx.setSessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash(false);
}
current.start();
ctx.addServletMapping("*.pdf", "jsp", true);
```

I have enabled the *.pdf mapping to jsp servlet (some issue I had with IE)
is there a way to enable GZIP with this config (I have no web.xml, but if needed I could add to make it work)
So far I have only found that I need to add this to my web.xml (which I don't have!)

```
<Connector port=”8080″ maxHttpHeaderSize=”8192″
maxThreads=”150″ minSpareThreads=”25″ maxSpareThreads=”75″
enableLookups=”false” redirectPort=”8443″ acceptCount=”100″
connectionTimeout=”20000″ disableUploadTimeout=”true”
compression=”on”
compressionMinSize=”2048″
noCompressionUserAgents=”gozilla, traviata”
compressableMimeType=”text/html,text/xml”/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edit: Updated property `compressableMimeType` to `compressibleMimeType` as per comment from `pieroxy`

I found that you can setup the properties like this:

```
Tomcat current = new Tomcat();
Connector c = this.current.getConnector();
c.setProperty("compression", "on");
c.setProperty("compressionMinSize", "1024");
c.setProperty("noCompressionUserAgents", "gozilla, traviata");
c.setProperty("compressibleMimeType", "text/html,text/xml, text/css, application/json, application/javascript");
```

I guess that this also applies for other connector property that you need to set up.

Comment: Please note that on Tomcat 9 the `compressableMimeType` property has been renamed  to `compressibleMimeType` and tomcat won't complain if you set a non existing property, no logs, no warning, nothing. Took me a while to get around that. Note that `compressibleMimeType` also works with Tomcat 7 so I suggest to edit your response to make it more future proof.