# Tomcat8 (After upgrade from tomcat7) breaks GZIP compression

Tags: java, migration, compression, gzip, tomcat8

I've been successfully using gzip compression with embedded tomcat 7. 
Example:
[Programatically enable GZIP Tomcat 7 (embedded)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304921/programatically-enable-gzip-tomcat-7-embedded).

After I ugraded to tomcat8, the responses started flowing in **uncompressed**.

Nor Tomcat8 configuration reference 
(https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html),
neither Tomcat8 Migration guide
(https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html)
mention this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly sendfile is enabled. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38693052/1667804